# Apache pig,programe issue

Tags: apache-pig

I am new to pig programming, i just trying one program that for the input given as below,

```
****Input:**gedit bomb**

sasi:where is the bomb
pras:bomb is with me
sasi:what is the bomb time
pras:it is set to nine.

****output:****

sasi:2
pras:1
```

It is number of times word 'bomb' occurs for each name(sasi,pras).

```
**Code:**

**A = load 'bomb' USING PigStorage(':') as (name:chararray,word:chararray);
B = FOREACH A generate(flatten(word)) as words;
C = FILTER B by words == 'bomb';**
d = group C by A.name;

i am confused from step 'd' ,can anyone say how to acheive the above mentioned output like 
sasi:2
pras:1


Thanks in advance.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
A = load 'bomb' USING PigStorage(':') as (name:chararray,word:chararray);
B = GROUP A BY name;
C = FOREACH B{
                filterByBomb = FILTER A by word MATCHES '.*bomb.*';
                GENERATE group,COUNT(filterByBomb.word);
             }  
STORE C INTO 'output' USING PigStorage(':');
```

**Output:**

```
pras:1
sasi:2
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, gettting the below error now:            2014-11-17 00:10:18,373 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt
- ERROR 1200: Pig script failed to parse:
<line 42, column 32> expression is not a project expression: (Name:
ScalarExpression) Type: null Uid: null)
Details at logfile: /home/hduser/pig_1416201061332.log

Comment: its actually line 4,column 32: i written code like  below:                                                               A = load 'pigex2' USING PigStorage(':') as (name:chararray,word:chararray);
grp = group A by name;
result = foreach grp
        {        filterbyword = FILTER grp by word MATCHES '.*bomb.*';
         GENERATE group,COUNT(filterbyword.word);
        }
STORE result into 'bombname';

Comment: ok got the problem. Instead of 'A' you gave 'grp' in the FILTER stmt. change your code like this. filterbyword = FILTER A by word MATCHES '.*bomb.*';